# Prometheus Pods restart in grafana

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus

I would like to have a Prometheus plot in Grafana to show (as a column chart) the number of restarts of the pods

How could achieve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can deploy the kube-state-metrics container that publishes the restart metric for pods: https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics

> The metrics are exported through the Prometheus golang client on the
>   HTTP endpoint /metrics on the listening port (default 80).

The metric name is: `kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total`

See all the pod metrics [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/tree/master/docs)